# Regular expression $ meta-character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to understand this code block. 

If the `$` meta-character ends the match, why is "I lost my wallets" valid? 

I understand that the quantifier `:?` allows for one `:` or none in the search, but why is there 2 of the same answers?

Can you figure out all possible matches for this pattern?

> "^I lost my:? (wallet|car|cell phone|marbles)$"

The given answer is:

> "I lost my wallet"
>   "I lost my wallets"
>   "I lost my: wallet"
>   "I lost my: wallets"
>   "I lost my car"
>   "I lost my car"
>   "I lost my: car"
>   "I lost my: car"
>   "I lost my cell phone"
>   "I lost my cell phone"
>   "I lost my: cell phone"
>   "I lost my: cell phone"
>   "I lost my marbles"
>   "I lost my marbles"

http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1
Quiz 2.2

Comment: I think it's just plain wrong. You can test it with a java regex tester, e.g.: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html - I lost my wallet will match, I lost my wallets will NOT match this regex.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/biSzLq/1/tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

It will not match it. It seems like a typo. They stated:

> if we did want to limit our pattern to just these results, we could
>   use add the required terminators to our pattern

They used the word **`limit`** our pattern **`to just these results`** that they provided which is not accurate. These two sentences will not match:

```
"I lost my wallets"
"I lost my: wallets"
```

Again, it seems just like a typo of the author.

Comment: Nice link. Shouldn't it match 'wallet' character for character and find 'wallet' as a substring of "wallets"?

Comment: @DuyĐặng Exactly, that's what will happen with `find()`  while `matches()` will not look for a substring.

Comment: @Ibrahim - So you're saying that `find` will **completely ignore** the `$` at the end?

Comment: @Addison You're right. I updated my answer. I was not paying attention to `^` and `$`

Answer (score 0):

The question posed in the [quiz](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1#section-11) (scroll down a little) is:

> Can you figure out all possible matches for this pattern?
>
> `"I lost my:? (wallet|car|cell phone|marbles)"`

The answer says:

> This is a trick question! Because this regular expression is unlimited (has no beginning `^` and no ending `$`)

After which is shows the piece of regex that you are looking at.

"I lost my wallets" is valid only with the regex shown above. The second one (in your question) does not allow it.

Here is an image describing the situation:

[image]